# CTE to display all my relatives regardless of the generation and extension (SQL Server 2016)

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, recursive-query

Just want to get the correct idea of how to best build a CTE.

I am after of getting all my relatives regardless of the generation and extension

For example:

- Parents/Aunts/Uncles/,Grand Parents, Great Grand Parents
- My Siblings/My Kids/My Nieces and Nephews

I can work out how to get either before or after but using two CTEs (recursive) and potentially using a temp table as reference to get nieces/nephews and merge them into 1 result.

Are there other options exploiting recursive CTEs?

Appreciate if you can lead me to best idea or answer.

I am thinking along the lines of "Get Parent" then "Get Child", does this child have another parent (different from the previous one), is this parent a child then loop back.

Below is my sample data

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

above is the perfect tree... but what if there is which 71 is my half-relative

```
60 | 70
60 | 71
61 | 71  
62 | 72   -- where 72 is half-sibling of 70 and 62 is a new spouse
```

> so the new expected result will be inclusive of 60, 70, 71, 72

Comment: What does the data look like?

Comment: Please edit your question , show sample data , what are you trying so far , and desired ouputs.

Comment: What is your input table and what is your expected output?

Comment: please check sample data cheers

Comment: please show expected result

Comment: result added cheers

Comment: I haven't got time to post a full tailored answer (we're putting out fires at work at the moment), but here's a tutorial I wrote on hierarchical querying in MSSQL a few years back: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/269629-developing-robust-hierarchical-data-in-mssql/

Comment: no worries. checked your logic pretty much the same as i was thinking.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Tnx but not related. Btw i already built the solution will post it tomorrow for reference

Comment: @e_i_pi please find my solution.. just temptables, loop and cte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Get Parent, Get Child, any Half relatives then Loop back approach 
>   Recursive CTE and Loop

```
/* relatives table */

create table #relationship 
  (rel1 int,rel2 int)

insert into #relationship 
values
(60,70),
(60,71),
(61,71),
(62,71),    -- half relative ie. 62 as Step-spouse considered as extended family
(62,72),    -- half relative ie. 72 as half-sibling of 71
(70,80),
(70,81)
,(80,90)
,(80,91)
,(81,810)
,(81,812)
,(91,100)
,(91,101)
,(91,102)
,(91,103)
,(91,104)
,(90,1020)
,(90,1030)
,(90,1040)
,(90,1010)
,(90,1050),
(100,1020),
(100,1030),
(100,1040)
,(100,1050)
,(101,1001)
,(101,1002)
,(101,2001)
,(810,81001)
,(100,1010)



/* you as 100 */
declare @inputval int = 100

/* need these variables for condition and switching values */
declare @initval int 
declare @testval int 

/* working table to get all child and parents and extended family */
create table #workingtable
(child int,
 parent int
)

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_rel1 ON #workingtable(child)

/* insert yourself for a starting point */

insert into #workingtable (child,parent)    --- set as parent
select top 1 @inputval,null

set @initval = @inputval

/*to include yourself in the loop as a starting point set this to 0 */
set @testval = 0

/* loop until all children has a parent as per relationship exists whether indirectly connected (half relative, step spouses) at least one connection*/
while (select count(1) from #workingtable  where parent is null and child <> @testval) > 0
begin

/*so the loop can carry on include yourself now... later on the ctes will find your parents and kids*/
set @testval = @initval


/*get your parents and everyone above*/
;with mycteParent (child, parent)
as
(
select child,parent from #workingtable with (index([IDX_rel1]))
union all
  select  n.rel1 [child],n.rel2 [parent]
   from #relationship n
   inner join mycteParent c
      on  c.child = n.rel2  
       where not exists (select 1 from #workingtable x where x.parent = n.rel1)  -- making sure it won't go infinite check if parent is already in the working table as parent

)
insert into #workingtable
select distinct child,parent
from mycteParent c
option (maxrecursion 0);


/*get your kids and everyone below*/
;with mycteChild (child,  parent) 
as
(
select child,parent from #workingtable with (index([IDX_rel1]))
union all

  select  n.rel2 [child],n.rel1 [parent]
   from #relationship n
  inner join mycteChild c
      on  c.child = n.rel1
        where not exists (select * from #workingtable x where x.parent = n.rel2) -- making sure it won't go infinite check if parent is already in the working table as child         
)

insert into #workingtable
select distinct child, parent
from mycteChild c
option (maxrecursion 0);


/* clean all nodes without parent but excluding yourself as the initial value*/
delete from #workingtable where parent is null and child <> @initval

/* get half relatives, these are people related to a child */
insert into #workingtable  (child,parent)
  select  distinct n.rel1 ,null
    from #relationship n
    inner join  #workingtable t 
            on t.child = n.rel2
    where not exists ( select 1 from #workingtable t where  n.rel1 = t.parent) -- making sure it's not already in the working table as a parent
    and not exists ( select 1 from #workingtable t where  n.rel1 = t.child) -- -- making sure it's not already in the working table as a child

end

/* merge and display unique nodes */

select child [myrelatives] from #workingtable
    where child is not null
union 
select parent from #workingtable 
    where parent is not null
    order by child

drop table #workingtable
drop table #relationship
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you are looking for.
I don't think there is any need for Recursive.

Still,don't have your real data in textual form.

```
declare @t table(rel1 int,rel2 int)
insert into @t values(70,80),(70,81),(80,90)
,(80,91),(81,810),(81,812),(91,100),(91,101)
,(91,102),(91,103),(91,104),(90,1020),(90,1030),(90,1040),(90,1010)
,(90,1050),(100,1020),(100,1030),(100,1040)
,(100,1050),(101,1001),(101,1002),(810,81001),(100,1010)

declare @input int=70


select t.rel1 from @t t
UNION
select t.rel2 from @t t
```

2nd Method,

```
select t.rel1 from @t t
inner join @t c
on t.rel2=c.rel1
union 
select t.rel2 from @t t
inner join @t c
on t.rel1=c.rel2
```

Comment: appreciate you building the schema for me but the requirement is to get all relatives including Uncle's kids or Great grand dad's other kids and/or any half cousins or uncles, regardless of the node it will bring all relatives top and bottom

Comment: mine give record of top and bottom both.what is wrong according to you as per my sample data.

Comment: You did not get the cousins and the kids from my other great granny

Comment: @maSTAShuFu,check my script still not able to imagine your rela scenrio and wht so touhg about it.

Comment: what if you added (60,70), (60,71), (61,71)?

Comment: please find the solution